# How to sync iTunes to iPad

Tags: itunes, macos

Now I have this iPad that's synced with my home iTunes. I need to add just one pdf onto it. So I installed iTunes here, but it won't sync iTunes to iPad. It wants to sync iPad to iTunes instead. Which is pointless, as the local library is empty. Both are logged on same iTunes account.

How do I make iTunes sync to iPad, so things can be **added** to the library and then synced back to iDevice?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sync will bring items from your iPad to your iTunes library. Once that is done via iBooks on your mac drop the PDF into that app. Then when you sync again that PDF will show up on your iPad.

Or you can just email (iMessage, AirDrop) the PDF to your iPad and then open it and save it into iBooks.

If the iPad already has media content then you will want to this - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4256950?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It will also lose all your music. iOS is the slave, iTunes… one iTunes, is the master.

Comment: it specifically warns me that beginning sync will wipe my iPad.

Comment: Updated answer regarding devices with content already on them